# res.send() express.js automatically redirect

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am using nodejs and the framework express.js to realize my website.

I am submitting a POST request on an url (/report/*reportname*)  *reportname* is a variable.

so I do this :

```
app.post('/report/:id', function(req, res){ 
   var id=req.param('id');
   var bodyreportHtml;
   go.prototype.runReport(id,res);
  }
```

The thing is  that in `go.prototype.runReport(id,res)`
I do a `res.send(bodyofthereport)`. 
So when I click on submit on my form that just redirect me on `/report/nameofthereport` where the pdf report  is. 
Everything is working but I would like to put this url `/report/nameofthereport` (the pdf report) in an iframe.
So when I submit the post request I want it just refresh the iframe and print the report in it ( the iframe is on the same page than the form).
But the `res.send(bodyofthereport)` is essential : it prints my report at `/report/nameofthereport` 
And I can't do a `res.redirect('/')` because the body is `finished`

How can I do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `POST` to an iframe, you could just set the `target` attribute of the `form` to the name of the iframe:

```
<form action='/report/ID' method='POST' target='FOO'></form>

<iframe name='FOO'></iframe>
```

Nothing node.js or Express specific about this!

Comment: Thanks but it's probably working, but when I submit it redirect me on another page (/report/reportname). And my iframe is on (/) so i can't see if it work ! I guess it's not the form who redirect me, but the app.post(/report/:id) in my app.js